# Terminal starts Blank on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 23.04

Hi I am new to ubuntu and I am using version **23.04**
Suddenly my terminal went blank and I even tried rebooting the terminal and the machine too but still it didn't work.

Even in VS Code, It does not open the terminal. Attaching the screenshots for guide:
Please help me anyone

[image]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Did you change the python version or any other significant changes?

Comment: No i didnt do anything

Comment: What happens if you start typing and/or press ENTER? Sometimes it takes a little while to load and other times it can appear to be stuck but if you start typing some stuff it kind of wakes it up. Also, try pressing CTRL+C a few times in case it's busy trying to do something, this can stop it from doing whatever it's trying to do.

Comment: Does it work if you rename the file `~/.bashrc` to something else? Can you [edit] your question and add the contents of that file, please?